# XML Comment Viewer Add-in for Visual Studion 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments, add-in

Wondering if anyone knows if the feature to allow add-in's for Visual Studio 2010 xml comment viewer was cut in the final release??  What I am talking about specifically is this:
[image]

I took this image from this page on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) I can't seem to find even one addin with this functionality, anyone know?

Thanks,

Jeff Lundstrom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a prototype someone built, not intended to ship.  As it stands, some people internally have played around with it, though still not with the intent of shipping it anytime soon.  Sorry :(

(It could be written as an extension, as the prototype was, but I'm also not aware of anyone else, internal or external, who has).

Comment: That is a total bummer.  I was at PDC 2008 and this was one of my favorite features of the new Dev Studio.  We just made the switch to 2010 and I was really looking forward to some great looking code.

Comment: Seconded, I saw this on the MSDN blog and immediately wanted to enable it in VS2010, now I come to find it doesn't actually exist. What a shame. :(